# MySQL selecting newest date before a given date to calculate SUM(#)

Tags: mysql, sql

I am doing an assignment for one of my classes and have searched high and low for an answer to my problem but am unable to find one.  I have two tables that I am working with.

They are:

```
TaxAreaAuthority                TaxRates
+--------------+---------+      +--------------+------------+-------------+
| TaxAuthority | TaxArea |      | TaxAuthority | Effective  | AuthTaxRate |
+--------------+---------+      +--------------+------------+-------------+
| city1        | city1   |      | city1        | 1993-01-01 |         1.0 |
| city2        | city2   |      | city1        | 1994-01-01 |         1.5 |
| city3        | city3   |      | city2        | 1993-09-01 |         1.5 |
| county1      | city1   |      | city2        | 1994-01-01 |         2.0 |
| county1      | city2   |      | city2        | 1995-01-01 |         2.5 |
| county2      | city3   |      | city3        | 1993-01-01 |         1.9 |
| state1       | city1   |      | city3        | 1993-07-01 |         2.3 |
| state1       | city2   |      | county1      | 1993-01-01 |         2.3 |
| state1       | city3   |      | county1      | 1994-10-01 |         2.5 |
+--------------+---------+      | county1      | 1995-01-01 |         2.7 |
                                | county2      | 1993-01-01 |         2.4 |
                                | county2      | 1994-01-01 |         2.7 |
                                | county2      | 1995-01-01 |         2.8 |
                                | state1       | 1993-01-01 |         0.5 |
                                | state1       | 1994-01-01 |         0.8 |
                                | state1       | 1994-07-01 |         0.9 |
                                | state1       | 1994-10-01 |         1.1 |
                                +--------------+------------+-------------+
```

Here is the main Question with examples:

> What is the Tax Rate for city2 on Nov 1, 1994?
>
> city2 = 2.0, county1 = 2.5, state1 = 1.1
>
> Total = 5.6

I am able to select the county and state from *TaxAreaAuthority* with these statements:

```
SELECT TaxAuthority FROM TaxAreaAuthority
    WHERE TaxAuthority LIKE 'county%'
    AND TaxArea='city2';

SELECT TaxAuthority FROM TaxAreaAuthority
    WHERE TaxAuthority LIKE 'state%'
    AND TaxArea='city2';
```

This is where I'm stuck.  My code for selecting the right date is off which is causing it to not add the right *AuthTaxRate* items together.

```
SELECT SUM(AuthTaxRate) as 'Tax_Total' FROM TaxRates
    WHERE EXTRACT(YEAR FROM Effective)='1994'
        AND TaxAuthority=(
            (SELECT TaxAuthority FROM TaxRates
                WHERE TaxAuthority='city2'
                AND EXTRACT(year FROM Effective)='1994')
            OR
            (SELECT TaxAuthority FROM TaxAreaAuthority
                WHERE TaxAuthority LIKE 'county%'
                AND TaxArea='city2')
            OR
            (SELECT TaxAuthority FROM TaxAreaAuthority
                WHERE TaxAuthority LIKE 'state%'
                AND TaxArea='city2')
            )
    ;
```

It returns this:

```
+-----------+
| Tax_Total |
+-----------+
|      11.5 |
+-----------+
```

But I need it to match the example he gave above.

Any Help would be greatly appreciated.  I'm pretty sure it is all due to the fact that I am not selecting the correct date to determine which *TaxAuthority* and *AuthTaxRate* to use.  Thanks again for all the help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You want to sum over the groupwise maxima.

First, find the relevant pairs of `(TaxAuthority, Effective)` by joining the tables and grouping the results:

```
SELECT   TaxAuthority, MAX(Effective) Effective
FROM     TaxRates JOIN TaxAreaAuthority USING (TaxAuthority)
WHERE    TaxArea = 'city2' AND Effective <= '1994-11-01'
GROUP BY TaxAuthority
```

Then join the result back to the `TaxRates` table:

```
SELECT SUM(AuthTaxRate)
FROM   TaxRates NATURAL JOIN (
  SELECT   TaxAuthority, MAX(Effective) Effective
  FROM     TaxRates JOIN TaxAreaAuthority USING (TaxAuthority)
  WHERE    TaxArea = 'city2' AND Effective <= '1994-11-01'
  GROUP BY TaxAuthority
) t
```

Comment: Thank you so much... this was exactly what I was looking for but I just couldn't get it organized in my head correctly!